# What is the sample size required to observe minimum numbers of each of two types of items?

Tags: binomial-distribution, sample-size

Suppose I have a large population consisting of 1 million items. 75% of these consist of type A and 25% of type B. I need to take a sample from the population but don't know until after the sample what the numbers of each type will be in the sample. My final sample needs to have a minimum of x of type A and and a minimum of y of type B. How many would I have to sample in total to be sure of achieving these numbers with 95% confidence?

Comment: What is the hypothesis?

Comment: @AdamO Interesting question, even though it's not relevant for understanding or answering this post.  It makes one wonder, though, what the statistical objective of these minimum requirements might be.

Comment: @whuber Hmm, maybe. I did go one route, the other route of "precision" or margin of error still doesn't have all the necessary details. If one does not actually know the sampling proportion of the A vs B, it doesn't make sense to pretend you can condition on the number of As and Bs you sample.

Comment: @Adam I interpret the question rather differently: how large must a random sample from a binary population (with the proportions described) be in order to have at least a 95% chance of containing the requisite numbers of each type of unit?  It's purely a probability problem whose solution depends on the type of sampling (with or without replacement) and the magnitudes of $x$ and $y.$ Collectively, such assumptions will determine whether a solution employs a Hypergeometric, Binomial, Poisson, or Normal distribution (the latter two being approximations, obviously).

Comment: It would be good to know rough orders of magnitude for $x$ and $y$. Are we talking about $x=10$ or $y=250,000$ (the entire population of type B)?

Comment: Yes x = 800 and y = 600

Comment: From the several interpretations, it's clear that the question is hopelessly poorly worded. (Voting to 'close'.) // To get a 95% CI with margin of error $\pm 0.5%$ for proportion of Type A. would take $n=40,000.$ If types A and B are the only possibilities, then proportion of type B would also be known. (While that's a large $n,$ it's still less than 10% of population size, so sampling with replacement is OK.) // If you just want to know whether it's A or B that's 25% then a sample of $n=10$ ten should be plenty.

Answer (score 4):

Let's begin with a general formulation of your problem.

You contemplate taking a sample of a population in some way.  A sample of size $n$ will yield two counts: the number of A's and the number of B's.  Let $X_n$ represent the count of A's, so that $n-X_n$ is the count of B's.  When the sample is random, $X_n$ will be a random variable.

The event of interest to you is that $X_n \ge x$ and $n-X_n \ge y$ where you have specified the thresholds $x$ and $y.$  We may combine these relations mathematically into

$$\mathcal{E}_n:\ x \le X_n \le n-y.$$

Given a probability $1-\alpha,$ such as $95\% = 100 - 5\%,$ you would like to find the least $n\ge 1$ for which $\Pr(\mathcal{E}_n)\ge 1-\alpha.$  To do so, we will have to develop a formula for this probability in terms of $n$ and then solve the inequality.

That's it for the formulation.  Let's turn to the analysis of your specific case.

With $x=800,$ $y=600,$ and a population of a million, it doesn't matter whether you sample with or without replacement, because you will find $n$ is going to be a tiny fraction of the population size.  Just make sure you sample randomly and independently.

Since there are a huge number of A's and B's in the population and the sample size obviously has to be at least $x+y=1400,$ that's large enough to guarantee that the Normal approximation to the distribution of $X_n$ will be excellent.  This simplifies the problem, because all we need to work out are the mean and variance of $X_n.$  The mean obviously is $E[X_n]=3n/4$ because $75\% = 3/4$ of the population consists of A's.  The variance depends a *tiny* bit on whether you sample with or without replacement.  When sampling with replacement, $X_n$ has a Binomial distribution with parameters $3/4$ and $n,$ whence its variance is

$$\operatorname{Var}(X_n) = (3/4)(1-3/4)n = \frac{3n}{16}.$$

As usual, it's simplest to standardize $X_n$ for this calculation, so re-express the event as

$$\mathcal{E}_n:\ \frac{x - E[X_n]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X_n)}} \le \frac{X - E[X_n]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X_n)}} \le \frac{n-y - E[X_n]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X_n)}},$$

which simplifies to

$$\mathcal{E}_n:\ \frac{x - 3n/4}{\sqrt{3n/16}} \le Z_n \le \frac{n-y - 3n/4}{\sqrt{3n/16}}$$

where $Z_n$ (the standardized version of $X_n$) has a standard Normal distribution. Writing $\Phi$ for the standard Normal distribution function, we find

$$1-\alpha \le \Pr(\mathcal{E}_n) = \Phi\left(\frac{n-y - 3n/4}{\sqrt{3n/16}}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{x - 3n/4}{\sqrt{3n/16}}\right).$$

That's a complicated mess: it needs numerical methods to solve, such as repeatedly looking up values in a table or--much better--using a root finder.  Deploy the latter by expressing the problem as

> Find the smallest $n\gt 0$ for which $$0 = f(n) = \Phi\left(\frac{n-y - 3n/4}{\sqrt{3n/16}}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{x - 3n/4}{\sqrt{3n/16}}\right) - (1-\alpha)$$ (and then round it up to the nearest integer).

It's not hard to show that such a root exists and is unique (because $f$ is a continuous strictly increasing function with a negative limiting value as $n\to 0$ and positive limit $\alpha$ as $n\to\infty$).

Here, as an illustration, is an `R` implementation using `uniroot`, its native root finding function, to find this zero of $f:$

```R
f <- function(alpha=0.05, x=800, y=600, A=0.75) {
  sigma <- sqrt(A*(1-A))
  f <- function(n) diff(pnorm((c(x, n-y) - A*n) / (sigma * sqrt(n)))) - (1-alpha)
  xi <- x/A + y/(1-A)
  ceiling(uniroot(f, c(1, xi - 8*qnorm(alpha)*sigma*sqrt(xi)))$root)
}
```

`pnorm` implements $\Phi.$

Most of the work (on the last line) is overestimating the sample size so that `uniroot` has a finite interval in which to search.  I use a rough formula that should work in any situation where this analysis applies.

This solution indicates your sample size should be at least $n=2544.$

As a check, I simulated 10,000 samples of this size from your population of one million, *without replacement.*  In 95.3% of these samples at least $800$ A's and at least $600$ B's were observed.  This percentage is not significantly different from the target of 95%.  Running such a simulation is a reliable, straightforward check of the answer (which, after all, was based on a series of approximations and assumptions).

Comment: Great answer. Just a couple of things about your r function. Why xi<-x/A+y/(1-A) and xi-8*qnorm(alpha)*sigma*sqrt(xi)

Comment: $x/A$ is the expected sample size to observe $x$ A's and $y/(1-A)$ is the expected sample size to observe $y$ B's.  I should have used the larger of the two values rather than their sum, but since all I need is an overestimate of the sample size for the upper endpoint of the search interval, the sum does fine as a point of departure.  The other term is a rough accounting for the variability of the sample.